# Seeding SQL Server by Entity Framework code-first approach with many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF6 code first with ASP.NET Web API.

Suppose there are two model classes

```
public class RawMaterial {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Furniture {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RawMaterial> RawMaterials { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext

```
public class FurnitureContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<RawMaterial> RawMaterials { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Furniture> Furnitures { get; set; }
}
```

And in the initializer class,

```
protected override void Seed (FurnitureContext context) {
    var glass = new RawMaterial { Name = "glass" };
    var wood = new RawMaterial { Name = "wood" };
    var paint = new RawMaterial { Name = "paint" };
    context.RawMaterials.AddRange(new RawMaterial[] { glass, wood, paint });

    var chair = new Furniture {
        Name = "chair",
        RawMaterials = new RawMaterial[] { wood, paint }
    };
    var coffeeTable = new Furniture {
        Name = "coffee table",
        RawMaterials = new RawMaterial[] { wood, glass }
    };
    context.Furnitures.AddRange(new Furnitures[] { chair, coffeeTable });

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I encountered a run time error complaining "an item cannot be removed from fixed size array". So clearly the program's trying to remove wood from chair before adding it to coffeeTable. So I changed the initializations to use Lists, as

```
var chair = new Furniture {
    Name = "chair",
    RawMaterials = new List<RawMaterial> { wood, paint }
};
```

After that, I could clearly see that wood was indeed removed from one of the furnitures' RawMaterials.

I also tried selecting wood from the context by

```
var chair = new Furniture {
    Name = "chair",
    RawMaterials = new RawMaterial[] {
        context.RawMaterials.Where(r => r.Name == wood.Name).FirstOrDefault()
    }
};
```

The result is still the same.

So my question is: how can I add the test data such that wood is present in both chair and coffeeTable? I am aware that this is not typically how many-to-many relations are defined, since RawMaterial does not know of Furniture. Or should I define the models the other way?

Thank you.

---

Edit:
I check the database tables in SQL Server Object Explorer, and the SQL for RawMaterial is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RawMaterials] (
    [ID]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Furniture_ID] INT            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.RawMaterials] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.RawMaterials_dbo.Furnitures_Furniture_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([Furniture_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Furnitures] ([ID])
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Furniture_ID]
    ON [dbo].[RawMaterials]([Furniture_ID] ASC);
```

And the SQL for Furniture is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Furnitures] (
    [ID]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Furnitures] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

So basically entity framework is not creating the database the way I need. That's why I cannot add wood to both chair and coffeeTable. How should I modify the Entity Models?

Comment: I can't reproduce an almost identical scenario using EF 6.1.3. Is this your real code or just a mock up for the question?

Comment: Yes it's a mock up. But I created a VS project at https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=429C201857BF4475!233&authkey=!AJSvTIbUHbHQHfw&ithint=file%2czip
If you'd like to reproduce, please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: I can run this code under .Net 4.5. Could you try that as well? I don't want to install .Net 4.5.2 on my dev machine. I can't imagine it's a .Net change causing this (at least, I hope not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was so focussed on the error you reported that I forgot to look at the mapping. But once I did that it suddenly appeared to be simple. It's a many-to-many association as you correctly indicate, but it's not mapped like one. This is how you map it correctly:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Furniture>()
                .HasMany(f => f.RawMaterials)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("FurnitureId")
                           .MapRightKey("RawMaterialId")
                           .ToTable("FurnitureRawMaterial"));
}
```

This creates a junction table `FurnitureRawMaterial` connecting both entities.

Still I think it's weird that I could run your code without getting the exception (and without getting the second "wood" association which I noticed later). I'd like to know if it's a .Net 4.5.2 issue.

Comment: I ran his code without getting any exception too. I also didn't get the 2nd wood displayed so I changed his Seed method and kept his model mapping. My dotnet version is 4.5

Comment: @JackyNguyen But your code inserts a duplicate, that should never happen.

Comment: I know, I did say it in my answer, I was just trying to help the OP display 'wood' twice in his console. Your answer covers many-many relationship for him, from there, he could create a DTO object handle add/update or use 3rd party like AutoMapper, maybe?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In the linked VS project, I used Lists instead of arrays, so you didn't see exception

Answer (score 0):

Base on your description, the relationship between Furniture and RawMaterial looks like many to many instead of one to many to me. One furniture can have many raw materials, meanwhile a raw material can belong to multiple furniture.

Anyway, back to your question, to display 'wood' twice, change your Seed method to this:

```
        var chair = new Furniture
        {
            Name = "chair",
            RawMaterials = new List<RawMaterial>
            {
                new RawMaterial {
                    Name = "paint",
                    FurnitureId = 1
                },
                new RawMaterial {
                    Name = "wood",
                    FurnitureId = 1
                },
            }
        };
        var coffeeTable = new Furniture
        {

            Name = "coffee table",
            RawMaterials = new List<RawMaterial>
            {
                new RawMaterial {
                    Name = "glass",
                    FurnitureId = 2
                },
                new RawMaterial {
                    Name = "wood",
                    FurnitureId = 2
                },
            }
        };
        context.Furnitures.AddRange(new Furniture[] { chair, coffeeTable });
        context.SaveChanges();
```

However doing this way, it will show duplicate name "wood", with different Id in your MAterial table